# Loans in Indo-Aryan languages indicating possible migration routes

Tags: proto-indo-european, substrate, indo-aryan

I am aware of only few Uralic loans into Indo-Aryan languages that show migrations from Eurasia to India, Iran etc. What are typical examples of loan words that are unquestionably a result of a migration towards those final destinations and not the opposite (as OOI theory suggests)?

Comment: There are Indo Aryan and Indo Iranian loans *into* Uralic but NOT vise versa. This does serve a problem into the current view of Indo European migrations.

Comment: Although not Indo-Arian, but Anatolian, check (2008) [Some Indo-Uralic Aspects of Hittite, Journal of Indo-European Studies 36](http://www.kloekhorst.nl/KloekhorstIndoUralicAspects.pdf) and perhaps [Introduction: Reconstructing Proto-Indo-Anatolian and Proto-Indo-Uralic] by Kloekhorst as well as a forthcomming Volume on the matter, at kloekhorst.nl

Answer (score -1):

There have been attempts to connect Uralic languages with the Dravidian languages* (one of the main linguistic families of India), but I am not aware of any attempts to relate Uralic to Indo-Aryan.  In any event, the general consensus is that such deep connections cannot be determined by a few word similarities.

*For e.g., you can read: Tyler, Stephen (1968), "Dravidian and Uralian: the lexical evidence". Language 44:4. 798–812.

Comment: The question is about loan-words, not cognates.

Comment: @AnubhavC: Clearly he is not talking merely about the loan words. He talked about the migration towards those final destinations and not the Out-of-India theory. The implication is a pre-historic connection.

Comment: There is no such implication. He's asking about loan words acquired in the course of migration.

Comment: That is correct @AnubhavC. I am looking for loans acquired in the course of migration.

Comment: @Midas: Could you list the loan words you have in mind?

Comment: @plotinus: Sorry for late answer. I have no words in my mind, I am asking for examples of such.

Comment: You say you are "aware of only few Uralic loans" into Indo-Aryan. Are you aware of any? If so, you could share them and we would know what you are asking about.